# d3.js brush fill color histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush, clip-path

i have created some histogram with `d3.js`. 
I managed to change fill color of `rect` depending on the position of the `brush`. 
But i would like to change the color inside a `rect`. For example if the `brush start` is in the middle of the `rect` i would like to have my `rect` with two color.

At the moment this is what i have :
[image]

And this is what i would like to have :
[image]

I have seen some examples like [Here](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/). I'm new to d3 and i try to understand the code.
I see that they use `clip-path` that certainly hide the background bar when their is no brush and show them when their is one depending on the range of the brush.

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/rifenulubo/edit?css,js,console,output)

## Update

I have read in details the code provided in the [link](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/). And i found that they dont create `<rect>` element to make chart but `barPath` like follow :

```
function barPath(groups) {
        var path = [],
            i = -1,
            n = groups.length,
            d;
        while (++i < n) {
          d = groups[i];
          path.push("M", x(d.key), ",", height, "V", y(d.value), "h9V", height);
        }
        return path.join("");
      }
```

But i didn't event understand what happend in this function and how to dot it in this way if their is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking to bring @Mark's answer to v6:

```js
const data = [{
  key: 1,
  value: 37
}, {
  key: 1.5,
  value: 13
}, {
  key: 2.5,
  value: 1
}, {
  key: 3,
  value: 4
}, {
  key: 3.5,
  value: 14
}, {
  key: 4,
  value: 18
}, {
  key: 4.5,
  value: 21
}, {
  key: 5,
  value: 17
}, {
  key: 5.5,
  value: 16
}, {
  key: 6,
  value: 5
}, {
  key: 6.5,
  value: 4
}];

// svg sizes
const width = 400,
      height = 200;

const m = 50;
const margin = {
  top: m,
  right: m,
  bottom: m,
  left: m,
};

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value))
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.key).map((v, i) => i==0 ? v - 1 : v + 1))
  .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

const rects = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'rects');
const clips = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'clips');

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis')
  .style('display', 'none')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg.append('defs')
  .append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', margin.left)
    .attr('y', margin.top)
    .attr('width', width - margin.right)
    .attr('height', height - margin.bottom);

const brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [x.range()[0], margin.top],
    [x.range()[1], height - margin.bottom]
  ])
  .on('brush', brushed)
  .on('start', brushed)
  .on('end', brushend);

function brushend(e) {
  if (!e.selection || !e.selection.length) {
    svg.select('#clip>rect')
      .attr('x', margin.left)
      .attr('width', width - margin.right);
  }
}

function brushed(e) {
  svg.select('#clip>rect')
    .attr('x', e.selection[0])
    .attr('width', e.selection[1] - e.selection[0]);

  const selected = {
    x0: x.invert(e.selection[0]),
    x1: x.invert(e.selection[1]),
  }
}

rects.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => x(d.key))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
  .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value) - margin.bottom)
  .attr('width', 20)
  .style('stroke', 'white')
  .style('fill', 'gray')
  .append('title')
  .text(d => d.key);

clips.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .attr('x', d => x(d.key))
  .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
  .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value) - margin.bottom)
  .attr('width', 20)
  .style('stroke', 'white')
  .append('title')
  .text(d => d.key);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x brush')
  .call(brush) // initialize the brush
  .selectAll('rect')
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('height', height)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to draw partial bars (as your edit seems to suggest), I would instead append the bars twice, once gray on bottom and then steelblue on top.  You can then just apply a clip-path to the blue bars and when they are clipped you'll see the gray below.

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    .charts {
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    
    .chart {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .axis text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      fill: black;
    }
    
    .chart text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      fill: black;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    /*dont display yAxis for categorical variable*/
    
    #chart .y.axis g {
      display: none;
    }
    /*Labels in categorical chart */
    
    text#catTitle.catTitle {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      fill: white;
    }
    /*Color for the brush */
    
    .brush rect.extent {
      fill: steelblue;
      fill-opacity: .125;
    }
    /*Color for the brush resize path*/
    
    .brush .resize path {
      fill: #eee;
      stroke: #666;
    }
    /*Color for the hidden object*/
    
    .hidden {
      fill: grey;
    }
    
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <svg class="chart" id="chart"></svg>

  <script>
    var data = [{
      key: 1,
      value: 37
    }, {
      key: 1.5,
      value: 13
    }, {
      key: 2.5,
      value: 1
    }, {
      key: 3,
      value: 4
    }, {
      key: 3.5,
      value: 14
    }, {
      key: 4,
      value: 18
    }, {
      key: 4.5,
      value: 21
    }, {
      key: 5,
      value: 17
    }, {
      key: 5.5,
      value: 16
    }, {
      key: 6,
      value: 5
    }, {
      key: 6.5,
      value: 4
    }];

    var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 41,
      bottom: 42,
      left: 10
    };

    var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.key;
      }) + 1])
      .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var chart = d3.select(".chart#chart")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .style("margin-left", 15 + "px");

    chart.append("defs")
      .append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x)
      .on("brush", brushed)
      .on("brushend", brushend);

    function brushend() {
      if (brush.empty()){
        chart.select("#clip>rect")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("width", width);
      }
    }

    function brushed() {
      var e = brush.extent();
      chart.select("#clip>rect")
        .attr("x", x(e[0]))
        .attr("width", x(e[1]) - x(e[0]));
    }

    chart.selectAll(".hidden")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "hidden")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.key);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", x(0.5))
      .style("stroke", "white")
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });

    chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.key);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", x(0.5))
      .style("stroke", "white")
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    chart.append("text") //Add chart title
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Petal Length");

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush) //call the brush function, causing it to create the rectangles
      .selectAll("rect") //select all the just-created rectangles
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", (height + margin.top)) //set their height

    function resizePath(d) {
      var e = +(d == "e"),
        x = e ? 1 : -1,
        y = height / 3;
      return "M" + (.5 * x) + "," + y + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (6.5 * x) + "," + (y + 6) + "V" + (2 * y - 6) + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (.5 * x) + "," + (2 * y) + "Z" + "M" + (2.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8) + "M" + (4.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8);
    }

    chart.selectAll(".resize").append("path").attr("d", resizePath);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```